# PostgreSQL SET runtime variables with typeorm, how to ensure the session is isolated?

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I would like to [set](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/sql-set.html) run time variables for each executed query without using transactions.

for example:

```
SET app.current_user_id = ${userId};
```

How can I ensure the session will be isolated and prevent race condition on the DB?

Comment: What do you mean with  "session will be isolated"? Values of session settings won't be visible to any other session/connection.

Comment: By the docs of typeorm the "connection" is a connection pool for postgres. How can I ensure using the same session/connection from the pool for both setting the runtime variable and for the query executed afterward?
I found some related issues in typeorm's github - 
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/5857
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/5313. A solution that is not dependent on the orm's api will also be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure the session will be isolated, you'll need to work with a specific connection from the pool. In postgres SESSION and CONNECTION are equivalent.
The relevant method of typeORM is `createQueryRunner`. There is no info about it in the docs but it is documented in the [api](https://typeorm.delightful.studio/classes/_connection_connection_.connection.html).

> Creates a query runner used for perform queries on a single database
> connection. Using query runners you can control your queries to
> execute using single database connection and manually control your
> database transaction.

Usage example:

```
const foo = <T>(callback: <T>(em: EntityManager) => Promise<T>): Promise<T> => {
    const connection = getConnection();
    const queryRunner = connection.createQueryRunner();

    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        let res: T;
        try {
            await queryRunner.connect();
            await queryRunner.manager.query(`SET app.current_user_id = ${userId};`)
            res = await callback(queryRunner.manager);
        } catch (err) {
            reject(err);
        } finally {
            await queryRunner.manager.query(`RESET app.current_user_id`)
            await queryRunner.release();
            resolve(res);
        }
    });
};
```

This was my answer also for [How to add a request timeout in Typeorm/Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63837096/how-to-add-a-request-timeout-in-typeorm-typescript/63860870#63860870)