# How to add a request timeout in Typeorm/Typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

Today, the behavior of Typeorm (Postgres) for

- `getManager().query(...)` and
- `getRepositoty().createQueryBuilder(...).getMany()`

is to wait for a response indefinitely.

Is there a way to introduce a request timeout that I might've missed?

If this is not possible, does Typeorm expose the connection from its pool so that I can implement a timeout mechanism and close the DB connection manually?

Answer (score 4):

You can change the default behaviour on a per connection basis either by using `statement_timeout` or `query_timeout`. You can read more about all possible configurations in the official node pg driver [doc](https://node-postgres.com/api/client). Difference between a `statement` and `query`?

> A statement is any SQL command such as SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE.

> A query is a synonym for a SELECT statement.

How to tell typeorm to use these configurations? Add these parameters under `extra` field in `ormconfig.js`:

```
{
  type: "postgres",
  name: "default",
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: 5432,
  username: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  synchronize: false,
  logging: false,
  entities: [
    "dist/entity/**/*.js"
  ],
  extra: {
    poolSize: 20,
    connectionTimeoutMillis: 2000,
    query_timeout: 1000,
    statement_timeout: 1000
  },
}
```

Note the use of `poolSize` here. This creates a connection pool of 20 connections for the application to use and reuse. `connectionTimeoutMillis` ensures that if all the connections inside the pool are busy executing statements/transactions, a new connection request out of the pool will timeout after `connectionTimeoutMillis` ms. More about connection pool configurations of `pg-pool` [here](https://node-postgres.com/api/pool).

Answer (score 2):

To work with a specific connection from the pool use `createQueryRunner` there is no info about it in the docs but it is documented in the [api](https://typeorm.delightful.studio/classes/_connection_connection_.connection.html).

> Creates a query runner used for perform queries on a single database connection.
> Using query runners you can control your queries to execute using single database connection and
> manually control your database transaction.

Usage example:

```
const foo = <T>(callback: <T>(em: EntityManager) => Promise<T>): Promise<T> => {
    const connection = getConnection();
    const queryRunner = connection.createQueryRunner();

    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        let res: T;
        try {
            await queryRunner.connect();
            // add logic for timeout
            res = await callback(queryRunner.manager);
        } catch (err) {
            reject(err);
        } finally {
            await queryRunner.release();
            resolve(res);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you this is smart. Would this also work with Repositories?

Comment: The `Repository` interface have a `queryRunner` member that you can use similarly. As far as I understand it is managed the same and supposed to work fine.

Answer (score -2):

[from the documentation](https://typeorm.io/#/connection-options/common-connection-options) you can use `maxQueryExecutionTime` ConnectionOption.

`maxQueryExecutionTime` - If query execution time exceed this given max execution time (in milliseconds) then logger will log this query.

ConnectionOptions is a connection configuration you pass to `createConnection` or define in `ormconfig`

Comment: From the documentation: connectTimeoutMS - The milliseconds before a timeout occurs during the initial connection to the postgres server. 
This is not the question. The question is regarding request timeout and not connection timeout.

Comment: can you please re-check my answer?

Comment: Reading this another time (and trying it) maxQueryExecutionTime doesn't do what I need to do actually. It doesn't timeout, it just logs when the response take more than maxQueryExecutionTime time.